# Round corner for BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet, material-components-android, material-components

I have a custom BttomSheetDialogFragment and I want to have round corners in top of Bottom View

This is my Custom class that inflates my layout that I want to appear from bottom

```java
View mView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.charge_layout, container, false);
    initChargeLayoutViews();
    return mView;
}
```

and also I have this XML resource file as background:

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <corners android:topRightRadius="35dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="35dp"
        />
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>

    <padding android:top="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:right="16dp"
        android:left="16dp"/>
</shape>
```

The problem is, when I set this resource file as background of my Layout's root element, the corners still are not rounded.

I can't use below code:

```java
this.getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.charge_layout_background);
```

Because it overrides the default background of BottomSheetDialog and there won't be any semi-transparent gray color above my Bottom View.

Comment: @RasoolGhana - Have a look at this link: https://medium.com/halcyon-mobile/implementing-googles-refreshed-modal-bottom-sheet-4e76cb5de65b

Answer (score 414, accepted):

Create a custom drawable `rounded_dialog.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:topRightRadius="16dp"/>

</shape>
```

Then override `bottomSheetDialogTheme` on `styles.xml` using the drawable as background:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">       
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
    parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppModalStyle"
    parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_dialog</item>
</style>
```

This will change all the BottomSheetDialogs of your app.

Comment: It works for me. Also I noticed it depends on layout root element. Firstly I had cardview as root (cause I tried another way to round corners), then I changed it to linear layout and now it works perfectly

Comment: Crashes on android api 17

Comment: I wouldn't use `rounded_dialog` & `AppModalStyle` names with a background where only the top corners are rounded, as you would only expect to use such a background with a bottom sheet style. How about `bottomsheet_rounded_background` & `AppBottomSheetStyle`

Comment: Note if you specify a background on the root view then this will override this setting

Comment: Can this be done without using a theme? When I use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` it causes all of my UI components to change colors and I can't override them

Comment: make sure you don’t have any background on root element of your sheet layout!

Comment: So many steps just to add rounded corners....Thanks for posting this though.

Comment: If you are using a toolbar on the top in BottomSheetDialogFragment then rounded corners won't show up.

Comment: Awesome!. This works. Make sure not to provide a background to your parent view in your layout.

Comment: In 2022 "Material 3 is the latest version of Google’s open-source design system. Design and build beautiful, usable products with Material 3." I change the parent attribute value in the last Style tag from Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal   to   Widget.Material3.BottomSheet.Modal  and it's working fine.

Comment: awesome. 100%  provided solution for me.

Answer (score 252):

With the new [Material Component](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) library you can [customize the shape](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md#customizing-component-shapes) of your component using the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute in your style (**Note:** it requires at least the version **1.1.0**)

Just use the [`BottomSheetDialogFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment) overriding the `onCreateView` method and then define your custom style for Bottom Sheet Dialogs.

Define the `bottomSheetDialogTheme` attribute in `styles.xml` in your app theme:

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    ....
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/CustomBottomSheetDialog</item>
  </style>
```

Then just define your favorite shape with `shapeAppearanceOverlay`

```
  <style name="CustomBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheet</item>
  </style>

  <style name="CustomBottomSheet" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog</item>
  </style>

  <style name="CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">16dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

---

You can obtain the same behavior overriding this method in your `BottomSheetDialogFragment` (instead of adding the `bottomSheetDialogTheme` in your app theme):

```
@Override public int getTheme() {
    return R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialog;
  }
```

In this case you are using this themeOverlay only in the single `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and not in all the app.

---

**Important note** about the **EXPANDED STATE**:

In the expanded state the BottomSheet **has flat corners** . You can check the official comment in [github repo](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/pull/437#issuecomment-536668983):

> Our design team is strongly opinionated that rounded corners indicate scrollable content while flat corners indicate that there is no additional content. As such, they do no want us to add this change with fitToContents.

This behavior is provided by the `BottomSheetBehavior` and it is impossible to override it.
However there is a workaround -> **DISCLAIMER:** it can stop to work in the next releases !!

You can add a `BottomSheetCallback` in the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`:

```
  @NonNull @Override public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);


    ((BottomSheetDialog)dialog).getBehavior().addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

      @Override public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
          //In the EXPANDED STATE apply a new MaterialShapeDrawable with rounded cornes
          MaterialShapeDrawable newMaterialShapeDrawable = createMaterialShapeDrawable(bottomSheet);
          ViewCompat.setBackground(bottomSheet, newMaterialShapeDrawable);
        }
      }

      @Override public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

      }
    });

    return dialog;
  }

  @NotNull private MaterialShapeDrawable createMaterialShapeDrawable(@NonNull View bottomSheet) {
    ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel =

      //Create a ShapeAppearanceModel with the same shapeAppearanceOverlay used in the style
      ShapeAppearanceModel.builder(getContext(), 0, R.style.CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog)
        .build();

      //Create a new MaterialShapeDrawable (you can't use the original MaterialShapeDrawable in the BottoSheet)
      MaterialShapeDrawable currentMaterialShapeDrawable = (MaterialShapeDrawable) bottomSheet.getBackground();
      MaterialShapeDrawable newMaterialShapeDrawable = new MaterialShapeDrawable((shapeAppearanceModel));
      //Copy the attributes in the new MaterialShapeDrawable
      newMaterialShapeDrawable.initializeElevationOverlay(getContext());
      newMaterialShapeDrawable.setFillColor(currentMaterialShapeDrawable.getFillColor());
      newMaterialShapeDrawable.setTintList(currentMaterialShapeDrawable.getTintList());
      newMaterialShapeDrawable.setElevation(currentMaterialShapeDrawable.getElevation());
      newMaterialShapeDrawable.setStrokeWidth(currentMaterialShapeDrawable.getStrokeWidth());
      newMaterialShapeDrawable.setStrokeColor(currentMaterialShapeDrawable.getStrokeColor());
      return newMaterialShapeDrawable;
  }
```

Comment: @Tadhg Use 1.1.0-beta01

Comment: Oh whoops, I’m on 1.2.0alpha02 in order to support the new wonky “spinners”. I was able to get this code working on 1.2.0.02 but it doesn’t utilise the new shape component stuff.

Comment: @androidguy thanks for feedback. I have to check it but it seems a bug of the library. In any case I don't work in the material components team.

Comment: I have reported this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144859239 If anyone has any further findings or solution for the issue, please reply. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting this error and crash on v1.1.0-beta02 `Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior`

Comment: It doesn't work if bottom sheet dialog is expanded. Any idea?

Comment: In my case, I have had to override shapeAppearance.              <style name="CustomBottomSheet" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet">
        <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog</item>
    </style>

Comment: @JoséCarlos In the expanded state it doesn't work because it is a default behavior. (https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/pull/437). I updated the answer with a workaround if you want to override the default.

Comment: This is neat, but it doesn't seem to work on my end.

Comment: Have found a way to have rounded corners even in expanded state with 1.1.0 version.
Just added transparent _backgroundTint_.
`<style name="CustomBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheet</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/transparent</item>
    </style>`

Comment: This was the perfect and latest answer. I need to mark this as answer

Comment: This had not worked for me. After a invalidating cache and restarting android studio it worked all of a sudden.

Comment: I must "inject" the theme by overriding `getTheme()`, because our app theme does not yet inherit from any Material theme. However, I am also facing an exception "Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior", like @hkchakladar commented. Has anyone else faced this issue and got it solved? It feels like some theming attributes are missing, but since we're using a Theme.Overlay... I find that weird. Still struggling with it after setting a bunch of Material theme attributes on the overlay.

Comment: this solution is also working with `com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0`

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. This is the latest solution as of 26 September 2021.

Comment: Not working as of Feb 2021

Answer (score 80):

The `BottomSheetDialog` is setting a default white background color , this is why the corners are not visible, In order to show them you need to make the background of the dialog transparent by overriding the style of the `BottomSheetDialog`.

Define this style In your `res/values/styles/styles.xml`

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/bottomSheetStyleWrapper</item>
</style>

<style name="bottomSheetStyleWrapper" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And set this style to your BottomSheetDialog

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chooser_bottom_sheet, null);
BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this,R.style.BottomSheetDialog); // Style here
dialog.setContentView(view);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Better than the accepted answer, because this way you can have different backgrounds on different BottomSheetDialogs

Comment: Now curve visible, but a transparent color throughout the screen on touch only the white color on bottom dialog is visible @Badr any corrrection?

Comment: That's the solution I was looking for, Totally hack free.

Comment: Solution with simple understandable explanation kudos @Badr

Comment: Elegant solution

Comment: The only one that worked for me. Thanks Badr.

Comment: omg for me this is only working solution

Answer (score 51):

create a shape named rounded_corners_shape

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>

</shape>
```

define a style

```
  <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
           parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_corners_shape</item>
    </style>
```

use this style on your custom BottomSheetDialogFragment like this, it will be work!

```
 public class CustomDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style. AppBottomSheetDialogTheme);
      }

      ...
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you add some clarification along with the code.

Comment: This is the right place to set theme for `Fragment`s.

Answer (score 26):

The simplest and cleanest solution, that worked for me, was to put the following 4 lines in onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) method of my fragment class:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View bottomSheet = (View) view.getParent();
    bottomSheet.setBackgroundTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    bottomSheet.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    bottomSheet.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

This will allow for your custom drawable with rounded corners to be properly shown once set as the background of the top level view of your fragment layout.

In essence this overrides the default BottomSheetFragment attributes regarding color, tintMode and tintList.

Using this, there is no need for messing with style resources.

Comment: only one worked for me, those fancy stuff on above with more upvotes are too much work and not working at all, and complicated if ypu have different background colors, just added a rounded background drawable with rounded edges and added your code, worked like a charm!

Comment: Same here, only one that has worked. Thank you @ak93

Comment: A simple and elegant solution that works perfectly!

Answer (score 25):

This worked for me.

Create a background drawable (e.g. named `shape_rounded_dialog`):

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/color_white" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
             android:topRightRadius="16dp" />
</shape>
```

Add the styles below:

```xml
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" 
       parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">

    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheetStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomBottomSheetStyle" 
       parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">

    <item name="android:background">@drawable/shape_rounded_dialog</item>
</style>
```

In your `DialogFragment`, override the method `getTheme()` to return your style.

```java
@Override
public int getTheme() {
    return R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme;
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective

Comment: this isn't work if you expand bottom sheet

Answer (score 14):

### Edit 2023, Oct: For Material3

The original answer approach still works for Material 3, but it has pixelated corners, so here is another approach to solve this for Materia3:

1. Create a Material3 BottomSheet style:

```
<style name="RoundedBackgroundBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.Material3.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/RoundedCornerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="RoundedCornerStyle" parent="Widget.Material3.BottomSheet">
    <item name="dialogCornerRadius">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/dialog_background</item>
</style>
```

`@color/dialog_background` is the sheet background color.

2. Apply the style to your `BottomSheetDialogFragment`:

```
class MyDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun getTheme() = R.style.RoundedBackgroundBottomSheetDialog
    
    .... 

}
```

---

### Original Answer

**Step 1:**

Create a `res/drawable` named as `rounded_background.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners
    android:topLeftRadius="32dp"
    android:topRightRadius="32dp" />
  <solid android:color="#D81B60" />
</shape>
```

**Step 2:**

Create this style to remove the dialog background:

```
<style name="NoBackgroundDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

**Step 3:**

Set the drawable to the root view of the dialog using `setBackgroundResource()` & set the style by overriding `getTheme()` method

Java:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public int getTheme() {
        return R.style.NoBackgroundDialogTheme;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = View.inflate(requireContext(), R.layout.bottom_sheet_profile, null);
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_background);
        return view;

    }
}
```

Kotlin:

```
class MyDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun getTheme() = R.style.NoBackgroundDialogTheme

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        val view: View = View.inflate(requireContext(), R.layout.bottom_sheet_profile, null)
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_background)
        return view
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

if( view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_background)) this line dose'nt work then try to set the background of the Xml format of fragment.

Comment: this loses dialog's behaviour

Comment: @c-an Thanks for this; I just enhanced the answer with a different approach; hopefully it helps

Comment: I tried so many other "solutions" before this worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: From time to time we always have to do some custom styling on bottom sheet and I think we will come back to this over and over again. Just saved your answer for future reference thanks.

Comment: This is the best solution. Good One

Answer (score 12):

If you use the [last version of material component](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you just have to override `ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.LargeComponent` (as the bottom sheet use this shape) and set the value you want like :

```
 <style name="ShapeAppearance.YourApp.LargeComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.LargeComponent">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">12dp</item>
 </style>
```

And then set in your app style :

```
<item name="shapeAppearanceLargeComponent">@style/ShapeAppearance.YourApp.LargeComponent</item>
```

[The solution of Gabriele Mariotti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57627229/7663077) is similar and works too but this one is simpler.

Comment: As compared to other it is a much better solution, because most of the  solution out there is base on set custom drawable

Comment: Looks nice. Does this also apply to `BottomSheetDialog` ?

Comment: Note to all: Using this answer will cause all component using `ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.LargeComponent` to have same cornerSize and family, not just Bottom Sheet. Check your style requirement and decide if you want change appearance for all component or just individual component or widget.

Answer (score 10):

I was checking the same thing today and yes you were right about following code

```
this.getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.charge_layout_background);
```

this applies to fragment background, so instead you should get the bottomsheet view from dialog window and change the background here is the code

```
 @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View rootView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_member_info,null,false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
        adjustUIComponents();
        dialog.setContentView(rootView);
        FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) dialog.getWindow().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
        bottomSheet.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.container_background);
    }
```

here bottomsheet is the actual view you want to change.

Comment: The only way i got this working. Btw i'm using `BottomSheetDialogFragment` so that logic is in the `onCreateDialog` method

Answer (score 10):

Answer by [Koma Yip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4625990/koma-yip) from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28937224/5273427) worked for me, you should try it.

> Create a xml in drawable , say dialog_bg.xml
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
>     <corners android:radius="30dp" />
>     <padding
>         android:left="10dp"
>         android:top="10dp"
>         android:right="10dp"
>         android:bottom="10dp" />
> </shape>
> ```

put this in your layout xml root node:

> set it as the background in your layout xml
>
> ```
> android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg"
> ```

and in `onCreateView()` put this:

> set the background of your dialog to transparent
>
> ```
> dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
> ```

Comment: This should be the right solution because it works for all DialogFragments without jumping through hoops.

Comment: **For me, there are still white corners behind my rounded corners.** So when I change the color of my drawable to red, your code works correctly and creates a rounded red rectangle, but behind that there is still a default white rectangle. The _"dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable..."_ code you wrote changes the color of the entire "darkened" area above my dialog, but again, it misses those two little corners. **Do you know what could be causing this issue?**

Comment: Adding on to my comment above, I should note that I had to change the code in _onCreateView()_ to _"**getDialog()**.getWindow()..."_ in order for my code to run. Perhaps this is why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @NickDev Post new question if you think this solution does not apply to your code and maybe we'll find a solution.

Comment: @Variag Thanks for reaching out; I actually came up with a cheap workaround where I cover the default bottom sheet modal dialog with a rectangle that is the same color as the darkened area behind it. Then I added a second rectangle with rounded corners on top of that. It's not ideal, but it looks great! I appreciate the help nonetheless.

Answer (score 8):

1. Create a shape drawable .. which we will use as background for bottom sheet .
   Provide the appropriate value for radius of top left and right corner .

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
       <corners
           android:topLeftRadius="24dp"
           android:topRightRadius="24dp" />
       <padding android:top="2dp" />
       <solid android:color="@color/white" />
   </shape>
   ```
2. Now create style for " Bottom sheet dialog fragment "

   ```
   <style name="BottomSheet" parent="@style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
           <item name="android:background">@drawable/drawable_bottomsheet_background</item>
       </style>

       <style name="BaseBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
           <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
           <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheet</item>
       </style>

       <style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="BaseBottomSheetDialog" />
   ```
3. Now create a custom class that will extend BottomSheetDilogFragment ,where you provide your style .

   ```
   open class CustomRoundBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

       override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme

       override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme)

   }
   ```
4. Now use this class wherever you want to have round corner bottom sheet . 
   eg

   ```
   class BottomSheetSuccess : CustomRoundBottomSheet() {

       override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottomsheet_shopcreate_success, container, false)
       }


       override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 8):

Simplistic solution:

```
class TopRoundedCornersFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme)
    }
}
```

In styles.xml

```
<style name="BottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bottom_sheet_dialog_bg</item>
</style>

<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetStyle</item>
</style>
```

Last, create a top rounded corner drawable resource (bottom_sheet_dialog_bg.xml)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:topRightRadius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: It also needs background transparent on `onViewCreated` which clears out background under radiused corners and you can actually see the corners `(view?.parent as View).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)`

Answer (score 5):

I know this question already has an accepted answer. I'd like to document the problems I went through and how I finally got it working so it is useful for someone on the future.

Firstly, I was using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` as the parent for our `AppTheme`. This meant @Gabriele Mariotti solution kept crashing with the error `Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior`. I fixed this by simply changing the parent to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`. This did not affect our theme in any way but the RTE was gone. You can also fix this issue by simply including the require items to your style. But I didn't bother figuring out which styles were required by BottomSheetBehavior.

Secondly, try as I might, but I couldn't get the actual Frame layout (which was the BottomSheetDialogFragment) uses to have round corners. I realized that setting this to an image Drawable worked but not with a shape or a `@null`. Turns out, it was because the `LinearLayout` I was using had a background defined. This was overriding any background in the style. Removing that finally resulted in rounded corners.

Also, I didn't require any background shape to be set to round the corners. @Gabriele Mariotti's solution worked as soon as I made the above changes. However, to set the background colour what I wanted it to be, I had to override the "backgroundTint" item.

PS: I'm new to Android dev, and am maintaining an old App that was made for internal use in our College. I'm not all that familiar with Android's layout system or with the material library. I guess that's why it took me 3 days to figure this out. I hope this is useful to someone in the future.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day explaining the change needed from Theme.AppCompat... to Theme.MaterialComponents... It was driving me crazy

Answer (score 4):

This answer is only for the issue of setting the background color to `Color.TRANSPARENT` after setting up a drawable with rounded background to the layout.

None of the answer worked for me to set the background color to `Color.TRANSPARENT` except overriding `setupDialog()` solution:

```
@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), 
R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, null);
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);
    ...
    ((View) contentView.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.transparent));
}
```

**BUT** the `contentView` you set for dialog here is not the `view` you get in `onViewCreated()` when inflating in `onCreateView()`. It breaks the standard flow, so may issue troubles like you can't use `View Bindings` - `Kotlin Android Extensions` in `onViewCreated()`

So I tweak a bit to set the background in `onActivityCreated()`:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    (view?.parent as View).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
  }
```

Hope this help who got same trouble

Answer (score 3):

Bottom Sheet Dialog with Curved shape and peek height

```
    <!-- BottomSheet Dialog -->
<style name="BottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheet</item>

</style>


<style name="CustomBottomSheet" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog</item>
    <item name="behavior_peekHeight">420dp</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

As pointed in other answers, when state is `BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED` corners will be flattened.

You can overcome this issue by setting `peekHeight` property of `BottomSheetBehavior` and using your custom style.

```
abstract class BaseBottomSheetFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment(){

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    
        if (state == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
            requireActivity().windowManager!!.defaultDisplay!!.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
            (dialog as BottomSheetDialog).behavior.peekHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels
        } else {
            (dialog as BottomSheetDialog).behavior.state = state
        }
    }

    override fun getTheme(): Int {
        return R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialog
    }
}
```

**CustomBottomSheetDialog Style**

```
<style name="CustomBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheet</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/CustomMaterialButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomMaterialButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="cornerRadius">@dimen/dialog_bottom_radius</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomBottomSheet" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog" parent="">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">@dimen/dialog_bottom_radius</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">@dimen/dialog_bottom_radius</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Perfect answer working like charm !! :)

Answer (score 2):

Shorter solution to disable flatting of rounded corners on STATE_EXPANDED:

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
    
    //Disable animator that flats the rounded corners
    (dialog as BottomSheetDialog).behavior.disableShapeAnimations()

    return dialog
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these two methods in your BottomsheetDialogFragment class.

```
public void setDialogBorder(Dialog dialog) {
        FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) dialog.getWindow().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
        bottomSheet.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        setMargins(bottomSheet, 10, 0, 10, 20);
    }

    private void setMargins(View view, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            p.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
            view.requestLayout();
        }
    }
```

Now call `setDialogBorder(dialog)` method in `setupDialog()` method of your BottomsheetDialogFragment class.

Now create a shape file in your drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />

    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

Now set background for the parent viewgroup dialog view in xml file.

```
android:background="@drawable/round_border_white"
```

Done!!

Comment: Which view do you use with setMargins?

Comment: FrameLayout bottomSheet ;
This one defined in setDialogBorder() method. This actually is the default view for the bottom sheet dialog in android. It will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the `bottom sheet theme` to achieve the top round layout

Create a custom drawable background_bottom_sheet_dialog_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
       android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
    <padding android:top="0dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

Then override bottomSheetDialogTheme on styles.xml using the drawable as background:

```
<!--Bottom sheet-->
<style name="BottomSheet" parent="@style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item 
    name="android:background">@drawable/background_bottom_sheet_dialog_fragment
    </item>
</style>

<style name="BaseBottomSheetDialog" 
    parent="@style/Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheet</item>
</style>

<style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="BaseBottomSheetDialog" />
```

This will change the background layout of your bottom sheet

**BottomSheetDialog**

```
class SheetFragment() : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    lateinit var binding: SheetFragmentBinding;

  override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog;
    val view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, null);

    binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view)!!;
    binding.viewModel = SheetFragmentVM();

    dialog.setContentView(view);

    var bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(view.parent as View);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(BottomSheetBehavior.PEEK_HEIGHT_AUTO);

    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object : 
     BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
            if (BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED == newState) {
               // do on STATE_EXPANDED
            }
            if (BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED == newState) {
                // do on STATE_COLLAPSED
            }

            if (BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN == newState) {
                dismiss()

            }
        }

        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
           // do on slide
        }
    })

    return dialog
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add shape with rounded corner, make it background for your root layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
 <corners
    android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/padding_margin_16_dp"
    android:topRightRadius="@dimen/padding_margin_16_dp" />
 <solid android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

make background transparent on your BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    (view?.parent as View).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
}
```

its work for Contraintlayout, Framelyaout, Linearlayout, Relativelayout.

Answer (score 1):

Complete Solution:

Add below style attribute to style.xml.

```
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
    parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppModalStyle"
    parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bottom_sheet_background</item>
</style>
```

Then use **AppBottomSheetDialogTheme** to create a bottom sheet dialog from your code.

```
private fun openBottomSheetTermsCondition() {
    val mBottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(),R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme)
    val sheetView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_travel_advice_terms, null)
    mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheetView)
    sheetView.tv_head.setOnClickListener {
        mBottomSheetDialog.dismiss()
    }

    sheetView.webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,getString(R.string.privacy_policy_body_html),"text/html", "utf-8", null)
    mBottomSheetDialog.show()
}
```

I use the below drawable to round the bottom sheet background.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/bottom_sheet_corner_radius"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/bottom_sheet_corner_radius" />
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

Bottom sheet xml bottom_sheet_travel_advice_terms.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/bottom_sheet_peek_height"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/spacing_normal"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_small">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/begin_horizontal_guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/begin_vertical_guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/end_vertical_guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_end="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/sheet_header_shadow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_tiny"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_header_shadow"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_head"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/spacing_normal"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:padding="@dimen/spacing_small"
            android:text="@string/term_and_condition"
            android:textColor="@color/greyish_brown"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/end_vertical_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/begin_vertical_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/begin_horizontal_guideline" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line_separation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
            android:background="@color/blue_gray"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_head" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/end_vertical_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/begin_vertical_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/line_separation" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

`setupDialog()` is RestrictedApi. The simplest solution that works as of `material:1.3.0-beta01` without touching themes:

`res/drawable/bs_background`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners
    android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
    android:topRightRadius="16dp" />
  <solid android:color="@color/dayNightBackground" />
</shape>
```

```
public class MyBsDialogFrag extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

@Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ((View) view.getParent()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bs_background);
  }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore in 1.4 :/

Answer (score 1):

firstly you should create a drawable xml file that contains a shape with a top rounded corner, name whatever you want.
I named it a bottom rounded_top_shape.xml

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
>
<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
    android:topRightRadius="16dp"
    />
```

then in your style.xml add this

```
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_top_shape</item>
</style>
```

then in your app theme add this line as bellow

```
 <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
    <!-- this line -->
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using material components theme, you can override the default behavoir of **BottomSheetDialog** by setting the background color to transparent then set the background of your layout to be rounded.

```
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/BottomSheetDialog</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BottomSheetDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/bottomSheetStyleWrapper</item>
    </style>

    <style name="bottomSheetStyleWrapper" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

**rounded_corner.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="26dp"
        android:topRightRadius="26dp"/>

</shape>
```

Then apply the shape to background of your bottom sheet root layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner">

    <!-- 
       other layout components
     -->

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**Note that** if you're having component like Webview in the bottom sheet layout, you may not be able to achieve the rounded corner as expected because Webview has a default white background. In this case, you can simply remove the background like this:

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found simple solution.
works with com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1

```
class MyBottomSheet: BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    
      override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            disableShapeAnimation()
        }
    
      @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi", "VisibleForTests")
      private fun disableShapeAnimation() {
            try {
                val dlg = dialog as BottomSheetDialog
                dlg.behavior.disableShapeAnimations()
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Log.e("BaseBottomSheet", "disableShapeAnimation Exception:", ex)
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix this issue is to extend BottomSheetDialog and create a custom class which suits your needs. You can do the same for layout xml file, and add background or any other customizations needed. This also has a benefit that you'll not be dependent on the id names used by Android(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet), while changing the background (though the change of id name rarely happens AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom drawable with rounded corner and set it as background of your BottomSheetDialogFragment's layout root

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
    android:topRightRadius="12dp" />

</shape>
```

And then simply add the below code to your BottomSheetDialogFragment class

```
@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), 
R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, null);
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent())
            .getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();
    ((View) contentView.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.transparent));
}
```

You can even play with the params to set margin like below

```
params.setMargins(50, 0, 50, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need `setFitContents=true`, I tried the solution by hooking `onStateChanged`, but it flickers from the straight to rounded corners once the dialog reaches `EXPANDED` state. It's quite annoying.

There is an alternative workaround that doesn't cause flickering, doesn't require using private APIs, and is more readable (imho).

Looking at the code of `BottomSheetBehavior` we find:

```java
  /** True if Behavior has a non-null value for the @shapeAppearance attribute */
  private boolean shapeThemingEnabled;
```

Turns out if shape theming is disabled, `MaterialShapeDrawable` will not be used. We find this in `BottomSheetBehavior.onLayout()`:

```java
// Only set MaterialShapeDrawable as background if shapeTheming is enabled, otherwise will
// default to android:background declared in styles or layout.
if (shapeThemingEnabled && materialShapeDrawable != null) {
  ViewCompat.setBackground(child, materialShapeDrawable);
}
```

Defaulting to `android:background` is exactly what we need, as this means complete control on how the background is rendered.

We can disable material theming by creating a separate style and setting `shapeAppearance` and `shapeAppearanceOverlay` to null:

```xml
<style name="Theme.YourApp.NoShapeBottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
  <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/Theme.YourApp.NoShapeButtonSheet</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.YourApp.NoShapeButtonSheet" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet.Modal">
  <item name="shapeAppearance">@null</item>
  <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Extend `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and override `onCreateDialog`:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  return new BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(),
                R.style.Theme_Grupin_NoShapeBottomSheetDialog);
}
```

The bottom sheet is now naked, without any background at all. So we can add any background we want, no animation will be triggered anymore.

Comment: This worked to get the dialog shape as you'd like, but it loses all the other setup attributes from the theme as well. Just FYI

Answer (score 0):

In `Material3`, after added this view in the layout, the round corner will be generated automatically:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDragHandleView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[image]

NO EXTRA code is needed.

Source: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheet.md

Answer (score 0):

Update your Dependencies to v1.11.0.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
```

[image]