# How can I make the corners of my bottom sheet dialog rounded?

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-bottomsheetdialog

I'm trying to make the top corners of my BottomSheetDialog rounded, but I haven't had any luck with anything online. This is what I would like for it to look like:

[image: Rounded Modal Bottom Sheet]

No matter what I've tried, I keep getting this:

[image: Not rounded Modal Bottom Sheet]

I've tried the method [here](https://medium.com/halcyon-mobile/implementing-googles-refreshed-modal-bottom-sheet-4e76cb5de65b) and using shapeAppearanceLargeComponent (what I'm using now).

Here is my code:

styles.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    ...
    <item name="shapeAppearanceLargeComponent">@style/CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">16dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">16dp</item>
</style>
```

BottomNavMenuFragment:

```
public class BottomNavMenuFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_nav_drawer, container, false);
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm showing the fragment:

```
BottomNavMenuFragment navFragment = new BottomNavMenuFragment();
navFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), navFragment.getTag());
```

Nothing I seem to do works. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852562/round-corner-for-bottomsheetdialogfragment/57627229#57627229

Comment: I have, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Your code posted above is different

Comment: I know, I tried it and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round corner for BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852562/round-corner-for-bottomsheetdialogfragment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After messing around with the possible solutions people posted, I figured out that my code was working fine, but the corners of my NavigationView were obscuring the rounded corners of the drawer. After adding some padding, the rounded corners are displaying correctly.

Comment: Can you please post your solution?

Answer (score 11):

Follow the below steps to attain top rounded corner bottomsheet:

**Step 1:** Create drawable `rounded_top_corners.xml` file inside `drawable` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

**Step 2:** Create below styles in `styles.xml`

```
 <style name="BottomSheetDialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/bottomSheetBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="bottomSheetBackground" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_top_corners</item>
    </style>
```

**Step 3:** Add style in `BottomNavMenuFragment` class

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.BottomSheetDialogStyle);
    }
```

That's it, the style will be applied to bottomsheet.

Comment: This will work not for anyone using the Material Component BottomSheet, see this answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852562/round-corner-for-bottomsheetdialogfragment/57627229#57627229

Answer (score 1):

Create a drawable and set it for the bottomsheet inside the setOnShowListener as below.(where R.drawable.bottom_sheet_bkg is my background xml file).

```
        val dialogBinding = MyBottomSheetDialogBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val bottomSheet = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext())
        bottomSheet.setContentView(dialogBinding.root)
        bottomSheet.setOnShowListener { dia ->
            val bottomSheetDialog = dia as BottomSheetDialog
            val bottomSheetInternal: FrameLayout =
                bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)!!
            bottomSheetInternal.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bottom_sheet_bkg)
        }
        bottomSheet.setCancelable(true)
        bottomSheet.show()
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create following shape in your drawable:

> drawable/rounded_corners.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#fff"/>
    <corners 
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then for the layout for your bottom sheet you can add this drawable as a background property.

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
```