# how to make an Angled cuts top app bar using material design?

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, material-components-android, android-shapedrawable

I found this guideline in material design io site, could anyone share your idea, how to make this using material design, not 3rd party plugin.
[image: Angled cuts top app bar using material design]

Trying to reproduce using cut shape & an overlapping bottom sheet of Material Design, I looking standard guidelines to make this UI.

Comment: You can use a [`MaterialShapeDrawable`](https://blog.octo.com/en/android-materialshapedrawable/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This component is called [`Backdrop`](https://material.io/components/backdrop#specs) but it is not available.

If the component is fixed you can use something like:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout     
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
   ..>

   <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout/>

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
       android:id="@+id/ll"
       ..>
```

and then apply to the layout a **`MaterialShapeDrawable`**

```
    val layout : ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.ll)
    val  radius = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.cornerSize24);

    val shapeAppearanceModel: ShapeAppearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.CUT,radius)
        .build();

    val shapeDrawable = MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel);
    shapeDrawable.fillColor = AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(this,R.color.white)
    ViewCompat.setBackground(layout,shapeDrawable);
```

[image]

If you want to use a `BottomSheet` you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57627229/2016562) using as **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`**

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.BottomSheetDialog" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">24dp</item>
  </style>
```