# Rounded Modal Bottom Sheet is not clipped to the rounded shape

Tags: java, android

The problem is modal bottom sheet is getting rounded with grey color but with white background of rectangular corner as I couldn't manage to clip or trim the rectangular white edges

**This is Shape file..**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <corners android:topLeftRadius="50dp" android:topRightRadius="50dp" />
    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    <stroke android:color="@color/purple_200" />

</shape>
```

**This is Bottom Sheet Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/edit_image_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edit_image_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Edit Your Image"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/edit_sound_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edit_sound_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Edit Your Sound"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/delete_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delete_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete Your Image"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**and this is a simple Bottom Shee tDialaog Fragment**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment;

public class BottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    LinearLayout layout;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.modal_bottom_sheet, container, false);
        view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_layout).setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND);
        view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_layout).setClipToOutline(true);

        return view;
    }
    
}
```

So, finally I need your support to have only rounded shape and get rid of rectangular shape behinde rounded shape.
thanx in advance....

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852562/round-corner-for-bottomsheetdialogfragment/57627229#57627229

Comment: Any Updates, Appreciate your support