# Bottomsheet rounded corner with state expanded

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bottomsheetdialog

I am facing a specific problem. I have a bottomSheet and I would like to put a radius on the TopLeft and TopRight corner. It works except when the bottomSheet.state is `STATE_EXPANDED`. So I found this solution

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi", "VisibleForTests")
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): BottomSheetDialog {
    val bottomSheetDialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog
    bottomSheetDialog.behavior.disableShapeAnimations()
    return bottomSheetDialog
}
```

But the problem is :
In my bottomSheet, I have an EditText and a button. So that the keyboard is below the button, I have to add this line of code in my `onCreateDialog`  method

```
bottomSheetDialog.behavior.state = STATE_EXPANDED
```

So when I add it, for some reason, the corners are no longer rounded ...

here you can find my current code :

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi", "VisibleForTests")
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): BottomSheetDialog {
    val bottomSheetDialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog
    bottomSheetDialog.behavior.disableShapeAnimations()
    bottomSheetDialog.behavior.state = STATE_EXPANDED
    return bottomSheetDialog
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.BottomSheetStyle)
}
```

And here my `Style`

```
<style name="BottomSheetStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
</style>
```

Do you know what can I do to make this work ? `bottomSheetDialog.behavior.disableShapeAnimations()`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852562/round-corner-for-bottomsheetdialogfragment/57627229#57627229

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the following code.

```
//create round_dialog.xml inside drawable
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="24dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="24dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="24dp"
    android:topRightRadius="24dp" />
</shape>


// update you theme file
    <style name="AddDocBottomSheetDialogTheme" 
parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppModalStyle" 
parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_dialog</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginHorizontal">15dp</item>
</style>



// Dialog class
class TestDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
private lateinit var binding: TestDialogFragmentBinding

override fun getTheme(): Int {
    return R.style.AddDocBottomSheetDialogTheme
}
}
```

Comment: The solution was : instead of using  `bottomSheetDialog.behavior.disableShapeAnimations()`, its better to create a new background