# How to add rounded corners to a Bottom Sheet in Android using BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am developing an Android application and I am using a BottomSheetDialogFragment to display a bottom sheet. However, I want to customize the appearance of the Bottom Sheet by adding rounded corners to it. I have tried different approaches, but I haven't been successful in achieving the desired result. Can anyone guide me on how to add rounded corners to a Bottom Sheet in Android? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re42Y.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round corner for BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852562/round-corner-for-bottomsheetdialogfragment)

Comment: The solution didn't work for me